# I want to make string which is influenced by variables changing (c++)

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I'm using stringstream in put variables in string like

```
int c;
stringstream ss;
string st;


ss << "some texts" << c;
st=ss.str();
cout << st;
```

but when i change the c and call back ss.str() again, ss.str() is saving
ex-int c, not new one.
Is there any functions or way to string is influenced by changing variable here?

Answer (score 1):

Stringstream doesn't bind to the variable, you have 2 options

1) Create your own class that binds to the int (saves a reference or something)

2) clear the stringstream like

```
ss.str(""); // clear stream
```

and then write to it again

```
ss << "some texts" << c; // set the stream again with modified c
```